# Why do we use "of " in these type of constructions?

Tags: prepositions

It's not very uncommon to find the sentences like:

> It looks like your teacher might have made a little **of a** mistake.
>
> It was the last I ever saw **of** him.
>
> Let go **of** an opportunity.
>
> I've kicked enough **of** these guys' butts.
>
> It was an end befitting **of** a Shinobi.
>
> He robbed me **of** my childhood.

I believe that these sentences still make sense if we don't place **of** in them. What is the use of **of** in these?

Edit: [Source of 1st in the best answer](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100507044248AA2F1nA)

For the last one:
[image: Source for the fifth one]

Comment: Did you write these sentences yourself?

Comment: No, I collected the material. Should I add source to each or a few?

Comment: The first and the last seem incorrect. And I think you haven't copied the second carefully.

Comment: Some **of** are the one that appears in Partitive Constructions. Others are idiomatic expressions.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh The second sentence was copied in error. It should be _It was **the** last I ever saw of him._ See [**this link.**](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=%22It+was+the+last+I+ever+saw+of+him.%22&oq=%22It+was+the+last+I+ever+saw+of+him.%22) Without the article, the search returns only this question.

Comment: _I've kicked enough these guys' butts_ is meaningless in English. _It looks like your teacher might have made a little of a mistake_ is merely a typographical error; the writer accidentally omitted the word _bit_ between _little_ and _of._ What does this mean: _How actually it is functioning as a?_

Comment: I would never say 'a little of a mistake'.

Comment: Two of the sentences you are asking about do not contain 'of a', so it's unclear what you're asking. And more than one sentence uses questionable grammar. Have you tried looking up *of* in a dictionary and reading the definitions and example sentences?

Comment: This question appears to ask for proofreading, unless it is about whether prepositions can be omitted. The answer to that is sometimes yes and sometimes no. There is no rule.

Comment: I can't see any way to interpret this question as 'proofreading'.

Comment: @snailplane Because it is asking whether specific examples are correct without giving the specific reason other than omitting *of*, which by itself is meaningless.

Comment: Also you are mixing usages of *of* as a preposition and as part of idioms such as [*let go of*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/let+go+of).

Comment: @user3169 he is asking because he doesn't know. If he knew the difference, I'm sure he wouldn't have asked it in the first place. This is a grammar question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding appropriate usage and correct grammar, I don't think — and the comments support this— that the resources you've taken the sentences from may be called reliable.

At the same time, all the sentences are quite understandable and can be transformed into something more readable. But even leaving them as they are, you can't avoid "of" in every one of them:

> 1. It looks like your teacher might have made a little of a mistake.

In this one, the answerer on the Yahoo page might mean to use the expression ["to make little of something"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+little+of), meaning "to minimize or belittle something".

> 2.It was the last I ever saw of him.

["To see of someone"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/see+of) is a set phrase meaning "to meet someone; be in contact with him/her"

> 3. Let go of an opportunity.

This really sounds weird since ["to let go of something"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/let+go+of) means "to release, as from one's grip" and it's a set phrase too.

> 4. I've kicked enough of these guys' butts.

You can't make do without the preposition *of* here as it expresses to whom the kicked butts belong.

> 5.It was an end [of] befitting of a Shinobi.

To me, this sounds even weirder than "let go of an opportunity", but even so, the preposition "of" asks to be inserted for it might indicate the connection between whatever *a Shinobi* is and being no longer suitable to or proper for someone or something ([see](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/befit) the meaning of the verb "befit"). In other words, it might answer the question - not an iota less weird than the sentence itself - *"Whose end of befitting it was?"

> 6.He robbed me of my childhood.

["To rob someone of something"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rob+of) is a set phrase and it means "to deprive someone of something, not necessarily by theft".

Comment: Could we say "let go an opportunity"? What "of" needed there?

Comment: No - as was said, "let go of something/someone" is a set phrase. "Let him go", "let them help you", etc. don't relate to this usage. "Let the opportunity go!" sounds yet weirder to me.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh - Although, there's an idiom "to go to waste", meaning "to fail to be used or taken advantage of". Maybe "Don't let the opportunity go to waste" might work, although I doubt it. If I were to use this expression, I'd sooner collocate it with words standing for food, drinks,  or something, maybe even money or talent, that really might be wasted and/or thrown away. "To miss the opportunity" would be much a safer choice.

Comment: I don't agree that befitting requires "of". A quick search in Google Books will show many examples without of: https://goo.gl/WSjdlc